# Problem saving a pre loaded Excel Workbook with multiple worksheets in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am running into the following error when trying to save a work book using the openxlsx package
"***Error in fill$fillFg : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors***". Has anyone run into this problem, and if so how was it solved?

The excel workbook  consists of multiple sheet with named ranges which are used in calculations on Sheet1 (Sheet1 has formulas which I would like to keep). I tried running the following and obtained the aforementioned error.

```
WB <- loadWorkbook('input/RCF_step_0.xlsx')
saveWorkbook(WB,'test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jonathan Attey! Can you make this question more reproducible? What steps did you do to create the workbook? If not created in R, can you reduce the problem to (say) 1-2 notable formulas on a sheet, walk us through what to put on a sheet, and then reproduce the problem in R?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans.  My apologies for my late response. Regarding the steps to create the workbook, it was originally a macro-enabled xlsx book (with VBA codes to save data and perform other functions) which was then saved in an xlsx format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the loading function that imports the `style.xml` into `openxlsx::styleObjects`. It looks like fill some unhandled case of `fill` is in your input file which is imported as `character()`.

When `openxlsx` attempts to write the `styles.xml` output, something like this is happening:

```r
fill <- character()
fill$fillFg
#> Error in fill$fillFg: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

You could try to replace the `character(0)` with `NULL` or remove it, iirc it is just a `list()`. Or you give `openxlsx2` a try.